# How do I add Chrome Extension to django-cors-headers whitelist?

Tags: django, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension that allows the user to POST to the Django server.

Currently, I am using django-cors-headers with the setting:

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

to allow my extension to POST to the specified endpoint. Of course, I don't want access to be completely open, and would like to limit CORS to only the Chrome extension. However, I am unfamiliar with what URL I would need to input into the django-cors-headers whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's a simple answer: *don't do it server-side*.

An extension with a [host permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) will ignore CORS headers and the request will be sent out regardless.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that anyone can write an extension and point it at my api? I'm doing POSTs so security is of concern.

Comment: Yes. And you can't prevent it with CORS. And you can't hide any secret API key in the extension either.

Comment: Got it - to be clear, CORS can whitelist only URLs, not Chrome extensions.

Comment: Seems like this is not the case anymore, adding to the "permissions" list in manifest.json does not help.

Comment: With the manifest v3, you can now use "host_permissions": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/host_permissions.