# AJAX keep detecting failure but no errors showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm working on a **chrome extension**. For now, it just checks, whether the user exists.

There is a form in plugin popup. User fill this form with his username and password and it's sent to server.

User is found in view, everything looks run correctly but **AJAX** returns failure for some reason.

This is a view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def api_authentication(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.POST.get('login')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if login and password:
            username = login
            if '@' in login:
                username = mainapp_models.User.objects.get(email=login).username
                if not username:
                    return JsonResponse({'success':0})
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            print user # IT's ok, user is found
            if user:
                return JsonResponse({'username':user.username,
                                     'success':1})
    return JsonResponse({'success':0})
```

This is AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#login-button-id').click(function () {

        var login = $('#input-email-id').val();
        var password = $('#input-password-id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/authenticate',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'login': login,
                'password': password
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('failure');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

And `JsonResponse` looks like this: `{'username': u'milano', 'success': 1}`

When I fill the form and send the data, `user` is found but 'failure' is alerted. Do you know what's the problem?

EDIT:

Alerts for Andy's answer:

Since `console.log` didn't work, I changed it to alerts:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("JQuery failed: " + textStatus + " with error thrown: " + errorThrown);
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
```

ALERTS:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT2**

Finally found a console logs:

[image]

Comment: Firstly there is a typo in your posted code, `uccess` instead of `success`. Then, when error callabck is fired, which error do you get?!

Comment: I tried to check errors using the code from the answer below. It does not log anything so I changed log to alert. The  result is at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I found the console log. I had to click on plugin - inspect plugin and get rid of all alerts since they remove inspect window. I've added console log at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin on chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056156/access-control-allow-origin-on-chrome-extension)

Comment: Another dupe, closer to Django: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37544602/934239

Comment: In short: nothing wrong with your code, either server-side or client-side - but extension manifest needs tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Check out this documentation and check that your permissions have been set-up correctly.

You need to add a domain that you are trying to access with your AJAX request to "permissions" array in your manifest.json. Something like:

```
permissions: [
 "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more debug would be handy.  Try changing your AJAX error function to report a little more (not much, but it helps):

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log("JQuery failed: " + textStatus + " with error thrown: " + errorThrown);
  console.log(jqXHR);
  alert('AJAX failed. Check browser console for more info');
}
```

Also, are you running your django app from the development server (./manage.py runserver)?  Do this and look for any helpful output like stack traces.  Could be as simple as a typo or a forgotten import in the Python code

Comment: Oh, and post the browser console log here so we can see it :)

Comment: That's the problem, it does not write anything into the console. I'm checking it realtime... don't know why..

Comment: hmmm, not a huge amount of help there. What does the Developer Network tab in your browser show is provided as the response?

Comment: Network tab doesnt show anything. It shows current web page things not plugin things.

Comment: Finally found correct console. I've added it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: sorry it won't let me comment above....  Looks like you're accessing over https and Chrome is insisting that you need an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  You'll need to add some headers to your JsonResponse in the Python view in order for Chrome to allow the data in.  Take a look here: http://enable-cors.org/server.html for a bit more information on CORS.

Answer (score -1):

Another suggestion - looking closer at your Python try changing:

```
if user:
```

to

```
if user is not None:
```