# How to make POST request to my HTTPS server from Chrome Extension?

Tags: django, google-chrome-extension, https

How can I make a POST to my HTTPS Django server on a Chrome Extension? I always get a 403 No Referer error because the source URL is chrome-extension://..., which is a non-secure source.

Answer (score 0):

I think your browser is blocking the request because of [CORS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1)

One solution may be change your manifest premissions as like:

```
"permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Tomás Gonzalez Dowling*'s answer, be noted that you must don't do it server-side. Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544602/how-do-i-add-chrome-extension-to-django-cors-headers-whitelist), an extension with a [host permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) will ignore CORS headers and the request will be sent out regardless. CORS can whitelist only URLs, not Chrome extensions.